# Query running twice within custom PDO Database class

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm currently attempting to create my own custom database class that will allow me to do basic things such as insert, update, and select from my database. I have the code working for my insert function but it's inserting twice and I'm not sure why. It's been a while since I've messed with the singleton pattern and am having quite a few issues today. Any help would be great. Thanks

The issue method in question here is the `insert()` method. It uses the `db()` method to get it's instance of the database connection.

Database.php

```
class Database {
    // Class Properties
    private static $_instance;
    public $pdo;

    /**
     * Returns a database connection
     * @return resource Database Connection
     */
    private static function db() {
        // Return Database Connection
        return Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
    }

    private function getConnectionProperties($property) {
        return $GLOBALS['config']['database'][$property];
    }

    /**
     * Singleton for database connection
     * @return class Returns one instance of the Database class
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to database
     * @return mysql PDO connection to mysql databse
     */
    public function getConnection() {
        try {
            //Attempt to connect
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->getConnectionProperties('host') . ';dbname=' . $this->getConnectionProperties('database') , $this->getConnectionProperties('username'), $this->getConnectionProperties('password'));

            //Return connection
            return $this->pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new PDOException($e);
        }
    }

    public static function insert($table, $params) {
        // Define initial query
        $query = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (";

        // Format rows to insert
        foreach(array_keys($params) as $field) {
            $fields .= $field . ",";
            $bindParams .= ":" . $field . ",";
        }

        // Add rows and bind params to query
        $query .= rtrim($fields, ',') . ") VALUES(" . rtrim($bindParams, ',') . ")";

        // Prepare Query
        $preparedQuery = self::db()->prepare($query);

        foreach($params as $key => $value) {
            $queryParams[':' . $key] = $value;
        }

        //Execute Query
        if($preparedQuery->execute($queryParams)) {

        }
   }
}
```

Calling `Database::Insert`

```
Database::insert("test_table", [
    'username' => "Joe_Scotto",
    'name' => "Joe"
]);
```

This code does work, the only issue is that it runs twice. I think this has something to do with the class getting instantiated twice but am not sure.

Comment: Your singleton pattern looks basically okay. Before digging into this code too much (which does not show obvious signs of repeating the `execute()`) have you verified that the entire script isn't being called twice? Assuming you are running this with a web browser rather than CLI, common reasons include: faulty rewrite rules, empty `src=""` attributes on `<img>, <script>` tags, an empty `url()` line in CSS, a missing favicon.ico rewritten to index.php by .htaccess. All of those will cause the same URL to be requested more than once by the browser.

Comment: Have a look in your web server log, or watch the Network console in your browser's development tools;  look for evidence that the script is actually being run twice when you only expect it to run once.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This is one of the weirdest things I've ever seen within PHP. I did end up getting it working, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rewrite a large portion of the class to get it working. This is the code that worked:

```
// Class Properties
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo;

/**
 * Grabs connection variables
 * @param  string $property Variable to grab from the config file
 * @return string           Returns a config value
 */
private function getConnectionProperties($property) {
    return $GLOBALS['config']['database'][$property];
}

/**
 * Returns pdo connection
 * @return resource PDO Object
 */
public function getConnection() {
    return $this->_pdo;
}

/**
 * Connects to database
 * @return mysql PDO connection to mysql databse
 */
public function __construct() {
    try {
        //Attempt to create connection
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->getConnectionProperties('host') . ';dbname=' . $this->getConnectionProperties('database') , $this->getConnectionProperties('username'), $this->getConnectionProperties('password'));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new PDOException($e);
    }
}

/**
 * Singleton for database connection
 * @return class Returns one instance of the Database class
 */
public static function getInstance() {
    if(!self::$_instance) {
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

/**
 * Inserts into the database
 * @param  string $table  The table to insert into
 * @param  array  $params Key and value pairs for use within the query
 * @return bool           True on success, false on failure
 */
public static function insert($table, $params) {
    // Define initial query
    $query = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (";

    // Format rows to insert
    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
        $fields .= $key . ",";
        $bindParams .= ":" . $key . ",";
        $queryParams[':' . $key] = $value;
    }

    // Add rows and bind params to query
    $query .= rtrim($fields, ',') . ") VALUES(" . rtrim($bindParams, ',') . ")";

    // Prepare Query
    $preparedQuery = self::getInstance()->getConnection()->prepare($query);

    // Attempt to execute Query
    if(!$preparedQuery->execute($queryParams)) {
        return false;
    }

    // If everything passes, return true
    return true;
}
```